# YouTube Data API Node.js quickstart.js problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube-data-api

I am currently running the quickstart.js code provided by https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs

After running `node quickstart.js` on my terminal, visiting the provided link, and authorizing my app with my Google Developers Console Project, it seems as if I should've gotten some type of code:

```
Authorize this app by visiting this url: *provided url*
Enter the code from that page here:
```

Where can I find the above referred to code? I can't seem to find it. It instead redirects me to my web app.

Please Advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the doc page you already quoted:

> [Step 4](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs#step_4_run_the_sample): Run the sample
>
> Run the sample using the following command:
>
> `$ node quickstart.js`
>
> The first time you run the sample, it will prompt you to authorize access:
>
> a. Browse to the provided URL in your web browser.
>
> If you are not already logged into your Google account, you will be prompted to log in. If you are logged into multiple Google accounts, you will be asked to select one account to use for the authorization.
>
> b. Click the Accept button.
>
> c. Copy the code you're given, paste it into the command-line prompt, and press Enter.

That is you have to copy the code given in the browser address bar (under the URL parameter `code=...`) and paste that at the prompt given by `quickstart.js`.